# How to programmatically set Desktop Background to solid colors in os x?

Tags: objective-c, operating-system

How to set a solid color as background in os x desktops programmatically?
Have found the way to change it programmatically using the image.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]setDesktopImageURL:url forScreen:screen options:nil error:&error];
```

URL - image file url,
screen - nsscreen object,
error - nserror object.

Would like to avoid the use of an external resource such as image files.
Please help

Comment: Can you add an image with the color in your bundle, and then load that with `setDesktopImageURL` ?

Comment: yes, that I can do. Am looking for a solution where I can ignore the use of the image in the bundle. and set an apple default solid colors.

Comment: Then maybe generate an solid color image in your code, store it temporarily in memory, and then use the function above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fwiw I've often wanted to set my bg to white but that specific color is missing, the code below should do it.

```
    NSError * err;
    NSMutableDictionary < NSWorkspaceDesktopImageOptionKey, id > * m = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary;

    m[NSWorkspaceDesktopImageFillColorKey] = NSColor.whiteColor;
    m[NSWorkspaceDesktopImageScalingKey] = @(NSImageScaleNone);

    // 1x1 png from wikimedia commons
    // may have side effects in a pixel appearing somewhere ....
    // ... couldn't find it though ...
    NSURL * url = [NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"1x1" withExtension:@"png"];

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setDesktopImageURL:url
                        forScreen:NSScreen.mainScreen
                          options:m
                            error:& err];
    if ( err )
    {
        NSLog ( @"Ooops %@", err );
    }
```

You can change the color to taste ...