# How to programmatically apply color filters on the screen?

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript, retina-display

I can apply color filters to the whole screen using [macOS settings](https://www.igeeksblog.com/how-to-enable-color-filters-on-mac/). I want to do this programmatically.

I'm okay with using private APIs (this is for personal use).

[image]

Comment: Are asking about the UI or the actual filtering code? For the latter, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/methods_and_protocols_for_filter_creation/color_adjustment_filters).

Comment: @koen I want to apply the filters on the whole screen. That link seems to be about editing images?

Comment: *Maybe* this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685678/how-to-programmatically-set-desktop-background-to-solid-colors-in-os-x/63719741#63719741 can help? Use your own image and something else for ```NSWorkspaceDesktopImageFillColorKey```?

Comment: @skaak I want to apply the filters to the whole screen, not the desktop background.

Comment: Not sure you can do that, best try I think is with Apple script.

Comment: I found https://gist.github.com/silesky/2da3a6bef1703e38d901ec9c623eecbd and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251014144 ? YMMV

Comment: Do you want to change the settings in the pref pane or do you want to apply a similar color filter?

Comment: @Willeke I don't really care how it's done, I just want to apply some color effects to the whole screen. (I.e., both are fine by me.)